# UNIX Command on comparing two folder and delete the difference

Tags: unix

I have two folder. I want to find the difference in the two folders and delete the difference.

Using:

```
diff -a folder 1 folder 2 | xargs rm -rf .
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you consulted [man diff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)?

Answer (score -1):

See `man diff` :  Compare FILES line by line.

Then you should type the following sentences to have FILES to compare.

```
(cd /folder_1;find . > /tmp/folder_1.lst)
(cd /folder_2;find . > /tmp/folder_2.lst)
```

Then, `diff` will say you how you go from one file to the other. But the result will not have the good shape to be handled easily (excepted by `patch`). If you just want files present in folder_2.lst only, type `comm -13 /tmp/folder_1.lst /tmp/folder_2.lst`.

You want to suppress them in folder_2 ? Pipe the result to `(cd /folder_2; xargs rm -rf`

Note, that `rm` will suppress whole directories, then warn you some files are absent (because removed with the directory).

`xargs rm -rf .` will add `.` to the list of things to be removed !!

Comment: This doesnt seem to answer the OPs question - they are clearly aware of diff.

Comment: Diff print something like this : « 1c1 \n < a \n --- \n > b » then I doubt the OP wanted to use diff to select files to be removed.